# Colloquial expression for something working very fast?

Tags: word-choice, expression-choice

I am looking for an expression as an alternative to **fast** in the following expression:

> Ever since they have constructed flyover/overbridge, traffic has been very fast.
>
> My laptop has been super fast, ever since I have had the ram changed.

Comment: *At blazing speed, speed of light, speed of lightning; fast as lightning; at cyberspeed; lickety-split; quick as a flash; hypersonic, supersonic, presto, pronto;* [thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/browse/fast).

Comment: *Flying*, though why not think of something new like "faster than a paparazzo whose just spotted an actress in short skirt". Adjust for tone appropriate.

Comment: Quick as a wink.

Answer (score 3):

I like ***"greased lightning"*** or ***"warp speed"*** for an expression meaning "super fast"

Comment: Lol! Thx @BrianHooper!

Answer (score 2):

For the traffic example consider:

*- zips along

 - quick as a bunny

 - races

 - jets*

For the computer perhaps:

*- rockets

 - jets*

Or a retro:

*like the dickens*

Answer (score 1):

You could say your computer *[goes like the clappers](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/like-the-clappers.html)*.

Comment: What a delicious incongruity!